# How is MSE divided by $\sigma^2$ always a chi-square distribution?

Tags: distributions, self-study, mse, chi-squared-distribution

If I have the expression below, how can I use y~N($\mu$, $\Sigma$) to show it is a $\chi^2$ distribution with ($_n-1$) degrees of freedom?

($n$-1)($s^2$)/$\sigma^2$ how is this ~$\chi^2$ $_n$-$_1$?

I recognize this contains SSE. I know that I should show the square root produces a distribution of $N$($\mu$, $I$) . I am lost at this point. I am thinking perhaps to substitute quadratic form into the original expression, then see what cancels? Or is this totally wrong?

Comment: It *isn't* always a chi-squared -- so you can't. If you make some additional assumptions above those you mention, it's chi-squared.

Comment: Here are the notes from a class I teach http://www.people.virginia.edu/~trb5me/3120_slides/6/6.4/6.4.pdf

Comment: @Taylor this helps & I followed most of this until slide 11. I am a beginning grad student and we haven't learned what's on slide 11, the calculus part of M$_x$(t). can you explain slide 11 so I can understand what happened there, or if not perhaps a video I that might give details?

Comment: Basically a moment generating function is another way to look at a random variable. It's a function of $t$ if you're using that notation. Usually I use a density function, but sometimes moment generating functions are handier. One of the biggest ways they're handier is when you add two independent random variables together. The mgf of the resulting sum rv is just the product of the two old mgfs.

Comment: To show $\sum\left( \frac{X_i - \bar{X}}{\sigma}\right)^2$ is distributed as a chi-square rv, I use MGFs. I know the left hand side is chi-square, so I can write that mgf down. The right hand side is two things added together. One of them is chi-square, so we can write that MGF down. From the previous slide I showed they're independent, so I can write two mgfs multiplied together. Isolate the unknown mgf, and you'll see it looks like a chi-square mgf.

Comment: I think these notes cover the definition of an mgf http://www.people.virginia.edu/~trb5me/3120_slides/3/3.4/3.4.pdf

Comment: @Taylor thank you very much. This is the level of detail I wasn't provided in class, and you have a great way of explaining things. Thank you again! If you would like to copy / paste this as the answer, I can vote on it as the one that helped.